# Differences between std::array and boost::array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, boost, std

It is fully safe to change `boost::array` to `std::array`? Can it cause any discrepancies?

Is `boost::array` better over `std::array` (performance?)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::array<T,N>` and `boost::array<T,N>` are standard layout aggregates containing nothing but an array of `T[N]`.

Their interaction with `namespace boost` and `namespace std` may be different (Specifically, ADL will find `std` functions for `std::array`, and `boost` functions for `boost::array`).

So, if there is a function `foo` in `boost`, calling `foo(some_array)` might work if `some_array` was from `boost`, and not if it was from `std`.

The only container algorithms currently in `std` are `std::begin` and `std::end` (and similar the new ones `size` `empty` etc if you include near-future ones).  Ranges v3 (or whatever gets published) might add some more.

There are more container algorithms in `boost` than in `std`.  Some of them might fail to build.

In the worst case, someone could write a function with the same name as a container algorithm in `boost`, with an argument that can implicitly convert from `std::array`, and the unqualified call to that function could result in a conversion after you change the variable type, while before it called the `boost` container algorithm.

Similarly, someone could write code that explicitly checks if a template argument is a `boost::array` and behave differently if it is.

Both of those are a bit of a stretch.

Finally, `std::array` has modern `noexcept` decoration, and boost has a public `c_array` member you can get at (the name `std::array` member variables is, I believe, not specified).  (via @Potatoswatter).  I'd personally expect `std::array` to have better support going forward, as `boost::array` mainly existed because `std` lacked the functionality.

Other than those corner cases, `std::array` should be a drop-in replacement.

Comment: Well… more differences are apparent if you compare the classes. `std` has modern `noexcept` decoration and Boost has a `c_array` member.